# How to run a script when a user authenticates Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel

I would like to know how to run a function when a user authenticates,

This is my function for log

```php
public function redirectPath()
{
    if (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')){
        $bitacora = TblBitacora::create([
            'accion' => 'Inicio de Sesión Admin Exitoso',
            'user_id' => Auth::id(),
            'ip' => \Request::ip(),
        ]);
        return '/';
    }
}
```

I would like to run this script

```js
@if(Auth::user()->??????????????????????????????????????????
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#mostrarmodal').modal('show');
        });
    </script>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has Authentication Directives

> The @auth and @guest directives may be used to quickly determine if
>   the current user is authenticated or is a guest:

```
@auth
    // The user is authenticated...
@endauth

@guest
    // The user is not authenticated...
@endguest
```

More information available at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade

Also I wouldn't recommend to log in redirectPath method in your controller. You can use events, an similar to what you want to achieve is provided as an example on Laravel docs. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/events#event-subscribers

Comment: what about run a function when the user connect to the app?? I would like to run the function only when the user connects in that specific moment

Answer (score 0):

**First Question Answer :**
You can check is user login in your blade file and add javascript or something like this in your view file :

```
@if(\Auth::check())
  <script>
  $(function() {
     $('#mostrarmodal').modal('show');
  });
</script>
@endif
```

If Authenticate user is an Admin

```
@if (auth()->check())
   @if (auth()->user()->Admin())
      // Put your js files here
   @else
      // this is for others role
   @endif
@endif
```

**Second Question Answer :** 
If you want to run a function if user is authenticate then you can do it like that :

```
public function check() {
    if(Auth::check()){
        $this->secondFunc(); // This will run if user is authenticate.
    }
    else{
        return redirect('auth/login');
    }
}

public function secondFunc() {
    echo "This is second function";
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer... but I have a problem... I only want to run the function when the user connects... only in that moment, in this way when I refresh the page it runs the function again

Comment: @Oscar I edited my answer & just added your second question answer also.

Comment: thanks a lot.. that make me understand more.. but that is not that I want.... I have an script in my html... I would like to run that script when the user connects.. like I put in my question

Comment: @Oscar do you mean, when Admin (role) connect, you want to run a js file ???

Comment: only when the user connects, I need to refresh the page and I don't want to see the script again

Comment: @oscar I added more on the answer, check it

Comment: yes, but that runs the script every time that I refresh.... I want to run the script only when the user connects and If he refresh the page.. the script shouldn't be load again

Comment: I think that @if(\Auth::check()) shouldn't be... maybe @if(\Auth::log()) or something like that

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS `localStorage` to help you to do it:

```js
@if(\Auth::check())
<script>
    if (localStorage.getItem('already_connected') !== '1') {
        $('#mostrarmodal').modal('show');
        localStorage.setItem('already_connected', 1);
    }
</script>
@endif
```

Now, if you refresh the page, unless you clear localStorage data, it will not show
run this function again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: do I have to put something on the controller? I don't see the modal when I connect

Comment: I think you can just call $("#mostrarmodal").modal("show"); without the $(function).  Will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I'm not seeing the modal when I connect

Comment: i think you are missing something else, if your localStorage does not have the `already_authenticated` key, this code should work fine

Comment: Where can I see if I have  the alredy_authenticated key?

Comment: open your dev tools (f12 on chrome), then go to Application, local Storage, choose your site and you will see any stored key in there.